# Have serial port working under Linux 64 bits with Java

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, rxtx

I need to connect to and use a serial port using Java from a Linux 64bits machine. In my case an USB to Serial adapter since laptop have no more serial port since a while...

After struggling a lot, I got it working. Then changing my laptop, I lost it ;(. But finally got it working again.

I'll document how to do it in the answer.. so I can find it easily back next time I need it :D

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the Java JAR file RXTX and the serial library for Linux (32 and 64 bits are different...).

Main library can be found here: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download

But a nice package with a run-install.sh copying libraries directly in right place can be found here: http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java

After that, make sure your user is member of correct groups. In openSuse, it requires `lock`, `uucp`, and `dialout` groups. Log off and login to make the groups effective.

To test it, there is a nice explanation and program here: http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Access_Your_Serial_Port_using_Java#Test_the_Installation_of_RXTX_on_Ubuntu_Linux